# How to distributed load GZIP File?

Tags: c++, gzip

I have a gzip file "dat.gz", the origin file contains only ascii text line by line. **The .gz file is generated by 'pigz -i'**

I want to load "dat.gz" into several process to do parallel data processing. **The program language must be C or C++. Under Linux**

For example, the origin file contains "1\n2\n3", and I load the .gz file into 3 process(p0, p1, p2),  so that p0 gets "1", p1 gets "2" and p3 gets"3".

I read the file format of gz here: http://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc1952.pdf , and I found that each block of one .gz file starts with "\x1f\x8b". So I cut the .gz file by "\x1f\x8b" into blocks. But when I use the decompress lib of boost to process the block, something goes wrong.

Maybe my method was wrong at root.

My test .gz file can be downloaded here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9DaAjBTb3bbcEM1N1c4OEg0SWc/view?usp=sharing

My C++ test code is following. Running by "g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -lboost_iostreams && ./a.out". It throws out an exception.

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 
>   boost::exception_detail::clone_impl >'
>   what():  gzip error
>   Aborted

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <sstream>

//define buffer size of fread: 128KB
#define BUFSIZE 128*1024

void get_first_block(char *fn) {
  FILE* fin = fopen(fn, "rb");
  char buf[BUFSIZE] = {0};
  int pos = 0;

  //skip first 2 byte
  fread(buf, sizeof(char), 2, fin);
  int i;
  while (1) {
    int sz = fread(buf, sizeof(char), BUFSIZE, fin);
    if (sz <= 1) {
      break;
    }
    for (i=0; i<sz-1; ++i) {
      if (buf[i] == (char)0x1f && buf[i+1] == (char)0x8b) {
        break;
      }
    }
    pos += sz;
  }
  //first block start: 0
  //first block end: pos + i -1
  int len = pos+i;
  fseek(fin, 0, SEEK_SET);
  char *blk = (char*)malloc(len);
  fread(blk, 1, len, fin);

  using namespace boost::iostreams;
  filtering_streambuf<input> in;
  in.push( gzip_decompressor() );
  in.push( boost::iostreams::array_source(blk , len) );
  std::stringstream _sstream;
  boost::iostreams::copy(in, _sstream);
  std::cout << _sstream.rdbuf() ;
}

int main() {
  get_first_block("0000.gz");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that decompressing is the bottleneck of your application?  It would be much easier if you just had one process decompress the entire file into a shared memory region that all other processes can then read from.

Comment: @5gon12eder But if the .gz file is about 10GB size?

Comment: I was assuming that all data is needed simultaneously by some process.  Of course, if you cannot fit the entire decompressed file into memory, this solution is not so good, unless you want to be super optimistic and hope for efficient swapping by the OS.  How is your data access pattern in the worker processes?  Would it be possible for the “decompression thread” to chunk the *decompressed* data as it goes and only send chunks to the workers (maybe via MPI)?  The workers would then dispose of the former chunk as they receive the next.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that there is more than one of those blocks in a .gz file, also see [the Wikipedia article about gzip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip):

> Although its file format also allows for multiple such streams to be
>   concatenated (zipped files are simply decompressed concatenated as if
>   they were originally one file), gzip is normally used to compress
>   just single files.

This is especially true for your test file, because if you additionally look at the "compression method" flag, you can expand the search string to 0x1F, 0x8B, 0x08 which only appears once at the very beginning of your test file.

When trying to split a .gz file into blocks, you've got to do some more parsing instead of just looking for 0x1F, 0x8B, because this can also appear inside compressed data blocks or other parts of the member.

You have to parse the members and the compressed data. Unfortunately, the header only contains the *uncompressed* length of the data, not the compressed length, so you can't just skip the compressed data without parsing it.

The compressed data will be deflate data (there are other, but unused compression types), see [RFC 1951](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt). For non-compressed deflate blocks (chapter 3.2.4), there's a `LEN` field in the header so you can skip those easily. But unfortunately, there's no length field in the header of compressed blocks, so you'll have to completely parse those.

Answer (score 0):

`pigz -i` compresses each block independently, which permits random access at each block boundary.  Between each block is an empty stored block, which ends with the sequence of bytes `00 00 ff ff`.  You can search for that sequence, and attempt to decompress after that.  There are 39 such markers in your example file.

There is nothing that prevents `00 00 ff ff` from appearing in the middle of a compressed block, not marking a block boundary.  So you should expect that occasionally you will get a false indication of such a boundary, indicated by a failure to decompress.  In that case, simply move on to the next such marker.